MSBuild is not deploying to an internal server from a GitHub self-hosted runner
I'm trying to get a self-hosted runner which I installed on one of our internal servers and configured with the repository we have in our GitHub organization, to deploy to another internal server. The code base is an old ASP.NET app currently using .NET Framework 4.5.2. For that reason, I'm using MSBuild in the GitHub workflow. I've been following a GitHub Gist I found that describes using MSBuild in the YAML file, specifically this section. However, that section uses placeholders, so I've been looking elsewhere to try and see how to specify parameters such as MSDeployServiceURL. I found this SO post with an answer that discussed that. However, the GitHub workflow still doesn't publish to the other server. And there's no errors, so I don't know what's wrong. Here's some code snippet from the YAML file:
    - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v2

    - name: Setup NuGet.exe for use with actions
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v2.0.0
      with:
        nuget-version: latest
        
    - name: Restore NuGet Packages
      run: nuget restore $env:Solution_Name

    - name: Build and Publish
      run: msbuild $env:Solution_Name /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/TimeTrack_Test" /p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy /p:MSDeployServiceURL=**localhost** /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:UserName="$env:DOH_Build_Account" /p:Password="$env:DOH_Build_Password" /p:PublishProfile=Default

How do I make MSBuild deploy to another server in our network, from the GitHub self-hosted runner?

What type of deployment are you trying to implement? (See "Choosing the Right Approach to Web Deployment".) Is the web server configured for the type of deployment you are implementing?

Interesting question. I've never been told about the different ways of doing a Web Deployment to a web server. Thank you for the link! Reading that page it seems to me that we use Remote Agent. Most people will deploy straight out of Visual Studio. There's a few, older TFS CI/CD that deploy to a web server. I'm trying to make GitHub's Self-Hosted Runner deploy to the server. I know the server has Web Deploy installed (version 4). But when I tried going to the URL in the article, it failed to find that endpoint.
